# calling vb dll in python

Tags: python, vb.net, dll, vb6

So I have a function in vb that is converted to a dll that I want to use in python. However trying to use it, I get an error message
 this is the VB function

```
Function DISPLAYNAME(Name)
MsgBox ("Hello " & Name & "!")
End Function
```

and this is how I call it in python

```
from ctypes import *
test = windll.TestDLL
print test
print test.DISPLAYNAME("one")
```

But I get errors so what is the right way of calling the dll

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Test\testdll.py", line 4, in <module>
    print test.DISPLAYNAME("one")
  File "C:\Python26\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 366, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 371, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: function 'DISPLAYNAME' not found
```

I have been looking around online but no solution so far. Can't use cdll since this is for c progs.

I have looked at some of the python and dll related questions but no solution so far works for my issue.

Comment: Can you access the `dll` from other languages?

Comment: Have you try to check that your function is exported by your dll? Check it with dependency walker http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: Can you confirm if it is VB6 or VB.net?

Comment: @MPelletier and others: have you possible found solution for this? I struggle with the same. TIA

Comment: @Intelligent-Infrastructure Sorry, I just do cleanup here :)

Answer (score 0):

I dunno the answer to your specific question, but if it's VB.NET, you can natively call it in [IronPython](http://www.codeplex.com/IronPython).

Comment: It's not the solution - I suppose. IronPython is completely different package, and the problem here is to use vb dll in python - which seems to be impossible at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a scoping issue, with out the Public access modifier, the function may not be visible to external callers. Try

```
Public Function DISPLAYNAME(Name)
MsgBox ("Hello " & Name & "!")
End Function
```

in your dll