# VB dll doesnt work in python with ctypes (function * not found)

Tags: python, vb.net, dll, ctypes

I struggle to create dll in VB which will be visible for python,

none of VB functions are visible when I import dll into python

Here's what I do:

1. Simplest ever VB class

> ```
> Public Class MyFunctions
>         Public Function AddMyValues(ByVal Value1 As Double, ByVal Value2 As Double)
>             Dim Result As Double
>             Result = Value1 + Value2
>             Return Result
>         End Function
>     End Class`
> ```

2. I save it as a dll (Build from Visual Studio 2010)
3. I try if it works by importing it into othoer VB project (it works fine):

> ```
>     Imports ClassLibrary1
> Module Module1
>
>     Sub Main()
>         Dim Nowa As New ClassLibrary1.MyFunctions
>
>         Dim Result As String
>         Result = Nowa.AddMyValues(123, 456.78).ToString
>         Console.WriteLine(Result)
>         Console.ReadLine()
>     End Sub
>
> End Module
> ```

3. I load it into python and try to use it:

> ```
> from ctypes import *
> MojaDLL = cdll.LoadLibrary("E:\\ClassLibrary1.dll")
> MojaDLL.MyFunctions
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "C:\Python25\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 361, in __getattr__
>     func = self.__getitem__(name)
>   File "C:\Python25\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 366, in __getitem__
>     func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
> AttributeError: function 'MyFunctions' not found
> ```

instead of MyDll.MyFunctions i also tried: `MyDll.MyFunctions() , MyDll.MyFunctions.AddMyValues(1,2) , MyDll.MyFunctions.AddMyValues`.

What's wrong here? I don't understand it.

PS. there's similar unsolved problem: [calling vb dll in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363305/calling-vb-dll-in-python)

Comment: PS. When I register dll it as a COM it work's fine

Comment: Maybe these articles will help: [How to Automate Exporting .NET Function to Unmanaged Programs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16310/How-to-Automate-Exporting-NET-Function-to-Unmanage) and [Unmanaged code can wrap managed methods](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8124/Unmanaged-code-can-wrap-managed-methods).

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do this. The DLL you’re producing is a .NET assembly, or, if you expose a COM interface, it’s a COM component.

Python’s `ctypes` module only supports [C ABI DLLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface).

Comment: aaaah :/ so is there any way I can use vb dll's in python? Aprat from COM, which seems to be not that robust (registering name, one dll per name, hard updates, etc. etc.)

Comment: @Intelligent-Infrastructure There may be a .NET binding for Python but I actually doubt it – COM seems to be the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`dumpbin.exe`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429) on your dll, with the `/exports` or maybe the `/linkermember` option to see what the actual exported names in the DLL are.